# Java - Testing if a character array is a palindrome by means of recursion

Tags: java

I tried searching for solutions, but all that I have found are for strings. What I am trying to do is to check if a character array inputted by the user is a palindrome. Here's what I have so far:

```
public static boolean palCheck(char[] a, int index, int start) {
    if (a[start] != a[index]){
        return false; //base case
    }
    else if(a[start+1] == a[index]){
        palCheck (a, index-1, start+1);
        return true; //recursive step
    } 
    else 
        return false;
}
```

It always returns true if the first and last elements of the array is the same. Where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Strings are char arrays

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi! I apologize for my ignorance. I will change my question once I get home. I am really grateful that this site exists, it is a really big help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning true in your equals situation, not your recursive solution (which is being discarded). You will also want to check for when the indices are out of range or when they are equal so your function terminates when you've finished confirming it's a palindrome.

edit:

```
public static boolean palCheck(char[] a, int index, int start) {
    if (index <= start) { 
        return true; 
    }
    if (a[start] != a[index]){
        return false; //base case
    } else {
        return palCheck (a, index-1, start+1); //recursive step
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! your explanation was perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach. Recursion.

```
public static boolean palCheck(char[] array) {
    return palCheck(array, 0, array.length-1);
}

public static boolean palCheck(char[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (startIndex >= endIndex)
        return true;
    else
        if (array[startIndex] == array[endIndex])
            return palCheck(array, startIndex+1, endIndex-1);
        else
            return false;
}
```

I have written two methods to be able to call it this way

```
String input = "AKKA";
palCheck(input.toCharArray());
```

instead of

```
String input = "AKKA";
palCheck(input.toCharArray(), 0, input.length());
```

What is quicker to write for `String input`:

```
boolean isPalindrome = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().equals(input);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! although I'm quite not sure why you created two palCheck functions.

Comment: I see! I would def use that in the future

Answer (score 1):

Add a check

```
if(index<=start) 
   return true;
```

Also change

```
if(a[start+1] == a[index])
```

to

```
if(a[start] == a[index])
```